# what is the process of creating an analysis project using sql server 2014 SSAS and visual studio enterprise 2015

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas

I have installed sql server 2014 Enterprise, as wellas Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise on my Windows 2012 Server Data Center Edition. I am unable to find any menu options under either Windows OS, Sql Server, or Visual Studio, which would help create an Analysis type project.
The goal is to create a Data Warehouse, and an OLAP cube - to learn and practice ms sql server based analysis.
When I look at the sql server 2014 installation summary, I can clearly see the analysis services installed.
What is the common starting point to create such analysis project?

Comment: For SQL Server 2014, the only SSDT-BI version with support is the VS2013 version: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42313. Support for BI projects in VS2015 is coming in preview form later this year, and AS projects will be backwards compatible and support SQL Server 2014. However until then, you will need to use 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BI project templates are a separate install.  You need to download [SSDT-BI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx).

Comment: I do have SSDT-BI installed as well, but I do not see any BI project types in Visual Studio. Where should I be looking?

Comment: This is for 2012 as I don't have 2015 but it should be the same. File -> New -> Project.  Under Templates, there should be a Business Intelligence section, like so: http://puu.sh/jwFnu/4951b1743f.jpg

Comment: No such section under 2015. Will pull down VS 2012 and try that.